# Passing stty size results to Erlang program through C

Tags: c, bash, erlang, stty

character.c:14:70: warning: cast to 'char *' from smaller integer type 'int'
      [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    sprintf(command, "erl -noshell -s program main %s -s init stop", (char*)out);

when I try without the pointer

```
character.c:14:70: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type
      'char' [-Wformat]
    sprintf(command, "erl -noshell -s program main %s -s init stop", (char)out);
                                                   ~~                ^~~~~~~~~
                                                   %c
```

I want to get the size of the terminal window through `stty size` and pass to my Erlang program so it can display text properly.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void){
  system ("clear");
  int c;
  /* use system call to make terminal send all keystrokes directly to stdin */
  system ("/bin/stty raw");
  int *out;
  while((c=getchar())!= '.') {
    char command[100];
    char output[100];
    int out = system("stty size");
    sprintf(command, "erl -noshell -s program main %s -s init stop", (char)out);
  }
  system ("/bin/stty cooked");
  system ("clear");
  system ("echo ok\n");

  // return out;
  return 0;
}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: `system("stty size")` doesn't return the size; it executes the command and returns the exit code of the command.

Comment: Tell me how casting a pointer to a `char` value is going to solve the problem at hand.

Comment: Why are you using `stty` for this? You can get the information directly with a function call.

Comment: To get the output that a command prints, use `popen()`, not `system()`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I am trying to pass an argument to my erlang program as a string., I am using stty because I want to continuously let the user press keys without pressing return